# HAP does not return any nodes?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

```
using System;
using BankNew;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //source.Deposite(float.Parse(txtBox1.Text));
            //source.TransferFunds(destnation, float.Parse(tbWithdraw.Text));
            //lblBalance.Text = source.Balance.ToString();

            HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
            string filePath = "http://localhost:50846/Website/TestSourceCode.txt";
            // There are various options, set as needed

            // filePath is a path to a file containing the html
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(filePath);


            if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
            {
               // HtmlNode bodyNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/body");
              HtmlNodeCollection links=htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");

                foreach (HtmlNode node in links )
                {
                    string title = node.InnerText;
                   // txtBox1.Text = title;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
            Response.End();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You are loading a text file and expect an HTML parser to find nodes? What does the file look like?

Comment: @oded:Sorry,I was trying different different files(text and html).by the way problem was solved by my-self after some research,any way Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After this its working now.....

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

HtmlDocument htmlDoc = web.Load("http://localhost/Website/TestSourceCode.htm");
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify your fix, `LoadHtml` expects a string of actual HTML content. `Load` loads HTML content from a URL, which is what you intended.